# Special div shrinking

Tags: css, flexbox

How should I change CSS such way, that

- if `width of screen` > `1100px`    then `left nav` width is constantly `555px`, but `empty -space` is shrinking to 0 when `width of screen` = `1100px`
- if `width of screen` < `1100px` then `left nav` width is shrinking and `empty -space` div still is 0px.

Right part (`div class=button` and `div class=right`) remains unchanged

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1310px;
  font-size:0.6rem;
}
.wrapper .left {
  flex-basis: 555px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.left__nav {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  color: darkblue;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.empty-space {
  flex-basis: 100px;
  flex-shrink:1;
}
.wrapper .right {
  background-color: orange;

  flex-basis: 462px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end; /*  align right (at end)  */
}
.wrapper .button {
  flex-basis: 193px;
  background-color: #3ab8a4;
  text-align:center;

}

/* style for this demo */
.wrapper > div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: lightgray;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.mark-center {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: red;
}
.container-small {  
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightgray;
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: auto;
  padding:1rem 0;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="empty-space">empty space
  </div>
  <div class="left">
    <a class="left__nav" href="#">Link3</a>
    Left Nav
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    Links right aligned
  </div>
  <div class="button">
    Button
  </div>
</div>
<div class="mark-center">
  &uarr;
</div>
<div class="container-small">
  Some content
</div>
```

Comment: That's what media queries are *for*. Why must solutions not use them?

Comment: @Roddy of the Frozen Peasbecause I think there must exist a way not to use queries. Yes I believe that it's possible not to use them in that case. I'll rephrase question  then

Comment: Why would you want to do that? You have a problem that lots of people have, there is a solution for this problem that lots of people use, but simply because you can imagine not using them you won't use them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to accomplish that is to add 2 wrappers, one for the `left` side and one for the `right` side, and with that you will be able to easily *center* where the left/right links wrapper meet.

Remove the `<div class="empty-space">empty space</div>` element in the markup/CSS and instead, to create the *empty space* at the left in the `left` side, simply add `margin-left: auto` to the `left_inner` and it will be pushed to the right.

Stack snippet

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1310px;
  font-size: 0.6rem;
}

.wrapper .left,
.wrapper .right {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  display: flex;
}

.wrapper .left_inner {
  margin-left: auto;
  flex-basis: 555px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.wrapper .right_inner {
  flex-basis: 462px;
  background-color: orange;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;      /*  align content right (at end)  */
}
.wrapper .button_inner {
  flex-basis: 193px;
  background-color: #3ab8a4;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.left__nav {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  color: darkblue;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.right__nav {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  color: darkred;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* style for this demo */
.wrapper>div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: lightgray;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.mark-center {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: red;
}
.container-small {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightgray;
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 1rem 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="left_inner">
      <a class="left__nav" href="#">Link left</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="right_inner">
      <a class="right__nav" href="#">Link right</a>
    </div>
    <div class="button_inner">
      Button
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="mark-center">
  &uarr;
</div>
<div class="container-small">
  Some content
</div>
```

---

*Updated*

To be able to fullfil both above requirement and to stack them vertical, centered, on narrower screens, you need a media query or a script.

Here is an updated version using a media query for less than 1000px (`max-width: 999px`)

Stack snippet

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1310px;
  font-size: 0.6rem;
}

.wrapper .left,
.wrapper .right {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  display: flex;
}

.wrapper .left_inner {
  margin-left: auto;
  flex-basis: 555px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.wrapper .right_inner {
  flex-basis: 462px;
  background-color: orange;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;      /*  align content right (at end)  */
}
.wrapper .button_inner {
  flex-basis: 193px;
  background-color: #3ab8a4;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.left__nav {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  color: darkblue;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.right__nav {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  color: darkred;
  text-decoration: none;
}

@media (max-width: 999px) {
  .wrapper,
  .wrapper .left,
  .wrapper .right {
    flex-basis: auto;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .wrapper .left_inner {
    flex-basis: auto;
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  .wrapper .right_inner,
  .wrapper .button_inner {
    flex-basis: auto;
  }
}

/* style for this demo */
.wrapper>div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: lightgray;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.mark-center {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: red;
}
.container-small {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightgray;
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 1rem 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="left_inner">
      <a class="left__nav" href="#">Link left</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="right_inner">
      <a class="right__nav" href="#">Link right</a>
    </div>
    <div class="button_inner">
      Button
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="mark-center">
  &uarr;
</div>
<div class="container-small">
  Some content
</div>
```

---

If you want the link and button wrapper to fill the width, give them a width and make their content center aligned.

Stack snippet

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1310px;
  font-size: 0.6rem;
}

.wrapper .left,
.wrapper .right {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  display: flex;
}

.wrapper .left_inner {
  margin-left: auto;
  flex-basis: 555px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.wrapper .right_inner {
  flex-basis: 462px;
  background-color: orange;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;      /*  align content right (at end)  */
}
.wrapper .button_inner {
  flex-basis: 193px;
  background-color: #3ab8a4;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.left__nav {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  color: darkblue;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.right__nav {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  color: darkred;
  text-decoration: none;
}

@media (max-width: 999px) {
  .wrapper,
  .wrapper .left,
  .wrapper .right {
    flex-basis: auto;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .wrapper .left_inner {
    flex-basis: auto;
    margin-left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .wrapper .right_inner,
  .wrapper .button_inner {
    flex-basis: auto;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

/* style for this demo */
.wrapper>div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: lightgray;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.mark-center {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: red;
}
.container-small {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightgray;
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 1rem 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="left_inner">
      <a class="left__nav" href="#">Link left</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="right_inner">
      <a class="right__nav" href="#">Link right</a>
    </div>
    <div class="button_inner">
      Button
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="mark-center">
  &uarr;
</div>
<div class="container-small">
  Some content
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using media queries:

```
 @media only screen and (max-width: 1100px) {
   /*your css code */
 }

 @media only screen and (min-width: 1100px) {
   /*your css code */
 }
```

Here's w3c schools link about media queries.

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp