# Center flex divs horizontally

Tags: css, flexbox

I have three divs that have different flex-basis. In order to make page responsive I want to put them  centered one under one if width of the screen is less then 1000px.
Here's my example on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/Y-Taras/pen/JrRLQM?editors=1100):

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1310px;
}

.left {
  flex-basis: 555px;
}

.left__nav {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.wrapper .right {
  flex-basis: 462px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end; /*  align right (at end)  */
}
.wrapper .button {
  flex-basis: 193px;
  text-align: center;
}

/* style for this demo */
.wrapper > div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.mark-center {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: red;
}
.container-small {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightgray;
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="links">
      <a class="left__nav" href="#">Left Nav </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
   Right
  </div>
  <div class="button">
    Button
  </div>
</div>
<div class="mark-center">
  &uarr;
</div>
<div class="container-small">
  Center
</div>
```

Help me to put them that way if width < 1000px next way:
[image]

Comment: Based on the fact that this question depends on your previous question, [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46394584/special-div-shrinking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46394584/special-div-shrinking), I closed this as a dupe and updated the other.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me you don't want `flex-basis`, you want `width` since these elements don't grow or shrink.

If so, you can use a media query and change the flex-direction to `column` *after* switching the `flex-basis` properties to `width`.

```
@media (max-width:1100px) {
  .wrapper {
    flex-direction:column;
    align-items: center;
  }
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1310px;
}

.left {
  width: 555px;
}

.left__nav {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.wrapper .right {
  width: 462px;
  /* display: flex; */
  /* justify-content: flex-end; */
  /*  align right (at end)  */
}

.wrapper .button {
  width: 193px;
  text-align: center;
}


/* style for this demo */

.wrapper>div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.mark-center {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: red;
}

.container-small {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightgray;
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: auto;
}

@media (max-width:1100px) {
  .wrapper {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="links">
      <a class="left__nav" href="#">Left Nav </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    Right
  </div>
  <div class="button">
    Button
  </div>
</div>
<div class="mark-center">
  &uarr;
</div>
<div class="container-small">
  Center
</div>
```